# Xcode Cloud does not show up in Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-cloud

I setup and configured Xcode cloud and everything worked and synced properly and I was able to see the same configuration in App Store Connect > Xcode Cloud

I accidentally deleted my project and git cloned it again. Now, if I try to create a workflow, it shows an error that "Xcode cloud has already been set up for this app". But I don't see the workflow in Xcode and everything is fine in App Store

How do I sync both App Store and Xcode so that my fellow developers also see the workflow in their Xcode